# How can i display image from mysql to table using php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code-

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('db', 'table', 'p/w');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("db", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM computers WHERE KEYWORDS='Computers,Desktops'");
    echo "<table border='1' width='100%'  >";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['MANUFACTURER'] . "</td>";
```

I want to display image from db stored as path here in one of the columns

```
echo "</tr>"; }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

can anyone help? thanks

Comment: I suggest you learn SQL and basic PHP first. Your query will NOT return the rows you're trying to use. And once you've figured that part out, adding an extra field to paste an img src into some html will be trivial.

Comment: now i have corrected my code, can you help now? thanks

Comment: check my answer.. is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('db', 'table', 'p/w'); 
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
mysql_select_db("db", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM computers WHERE KEYWORDS='Computers,Desktops'"); 
echo "<table border='1' width='100%' >"; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['MANUFACTURER'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='folder_name/".$row['image_name']."'></td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**folder_name**=Name of the folder where image is saved
**image_name**=field name of the image in your table name computers

Comment: still u have not tick my answer...if u think my answer helped u... just tick mark my answer present at left side of above answer below arrows with zero 0

Comment: but it makes a new row for every new image you show , what do you want to say about that ? how do we show things on the same row but different columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the img element wherever you want to show the image.

`echo "<img src='" . $row['image'] . "'>"`. You can also check [img element for HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) or [img element for HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_img.asp)